# decode token in React Native

Tags: react-native, decode, jwt, verify

Is there any library / NPM module / code sample to verify and decode a JWT in React Native? like jsonwebtoken(does not work in React Native)jsonwebtoken dont works in react native  for verify jwt token

Comment: JWT verification usually happens on the backend side, why do you need it on the front-end? This could lead to a security breach

Comment: I suppose u find some way to do this... but still its a very bad practise to do so. Can u pls say what is the use case to which you want to implement this? Do it in the api server

Comment: i received token from backend laravel with jwt , i want to verify this token with secret Public Key to verify if signature is valid and get the payload . i used jsonwebtoken for reactjs but with react native dont works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve this problem by using `jwt-decode` library .

firstly i decode the token thene verify the Identifies principal that issued the JWT. if the iss is from my site i use the token and if it is not from my site i destroy the token